# aggregation operation in cloud bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I was going through BT documentation. Learned that data is stored in a column for a column family and accessed via row key. I want to understand if aggregation(such as count, sum) can be done by BT?
As Cassandra or Scylla DB share a similar data model and provides the aggregation functionality. So heavy lifting is done at the Db side rather than application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have almost the idea. You should keep in mind somethings stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview):

- BT is a NoSQL database service.
- BT is not a relation database.
- It does not suport SQL Queries, joins or mulit-row transactions
- It works better with high volume of data and access (At least 1 TB)
- BT offers a milisecond latency. etc,

There are [some solutions](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable#section-11) that might be of your interest. (Integrations with `Beam`, `Dataflow`, `BigQuery` and `JanusGraph`). I would like to share this about [Querying BT data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable). Just keep in mind that this feature is still in Beta.

If I understood correctly, you are designing the architecture of your solution, so this is the best phase to consider all your options, not only with the technical requirements but with your business requirements.

In a nutshell, if after all BT fits to your needs, you might consider Big Query to query your databse.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.